# How To Integrate Data Table in angular 6

Tags: angular, datatable

I new in angular version 6. I want to integrate data table in some module I use
 http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started this reference but it gives me Error like.
**angular-datatables.js:1353 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined**

this is my angular.json file code

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
 "version": 1,
 "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
"lagao-boli-admin": {
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "schematics": {},
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/lbadmin",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "lbadmin:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "lbadmin:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "lbadmin:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
"lagao-boli-admin-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e/",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "lbadmin:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "lbadmin:serve:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

},
"defaultProject": "lbadmin"
}

So How can we use data table in angular 6 please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the AngularJS version installed.

Try this:

```
npm install angular-datatables@6.0.0
```

Reference: https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1301